# Can I consume a node js server and asp.net web service simultinously?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js, design-patterns

I am new to Node.js, but I've been developing with .NET for a while, lately I've been reading about Node.js and its advantages and I think it's a great way to mantain code and also it encourages code reusability. However I have quite a dilemma here.

I know that I can now create a web application just with node js and javascript because now there are drivers to connect directly to different DB systems. However I don't know if that would be a good approach due to the fact that this is a new technology and I also want to take advantages of all the great .NET features but don't want to leave .NET aside.

So I created an image that is similar to what I want, please let me know if you see anything wrong with this, and if you have any recommendations you're most welcome to do so, thanks.

1- [image]

Answer (score 0):

From angular js perspective, it doesn't matter if it is NodeJS or .NET, so picking one Server technology stack and sticking with it will prove beneficial. I think it would be cumbersome to maintain two server side technology stacks in longer term. That being said, to answer your question, Yes, you can use NodeJS and .Net the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you both your .NET and NodeJS apps are serving a REST API, then it really doesn't matter to the client side. What you're essentially doing is running micro-services which has the benefit of powering different parts of your app using different stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you have to specify different open ports for every server that you run if both servers shares the same hardware. And from AngularJS perspective it doesn't matter like said Chandrakant Sutar.

Obviously .NET is more mature than NodeJS and from my experience NodeJS is still having important security breaches so for now I would not leave .NET if your project requires special security attentions. NodeJS is good for some of tasks but not for all...